# Ubuntu 16.04: USB stick mounts, but standard user has no access

Tags: usb, permissions, files

My kids have on our home PC for security reasons only standard user access, but they want to use their USB sticks. But only I have access (Admin). On the kids accounts the usb stick mounts, but they are not granted any access, they can format it but even then - no further access. I tried to give them access via a group, but I can't activate this group in the Properties/Permission menu - it always switches back to the old content. I already tried several other methods (i.e. Chmod) suggested on the internet - didn't work. On windows 7 there is no problem with the USB stick at all. And, yes, I have formatted it several time (Fat32.0)
Any ideas / suggestions ?
TIA, Joe eoJ